# Angular Scalable Enterprise Architecture

Tags: angular, webpack

I need to develop an Enterprise Level Application (front-end in **Angular 4/5**) with different subscription plan to users. A different subscription plan has different feature set.

I am planning to :

1. Create **Core Module** comprises **abstract business logic classes**, **HTTP Services**, **Interceptors** and **Core Redux Store** (action,reducer,effects)
2. Create **Separate Feature Module** for every subscription plan and override business logic layer and add extra action, effects and reducers. It will also contain plan specific Angular components

I have below questions:

1. **Can each feature module be created as separate bundle using angular-cli or Webpack?** So that user downloads its subscribed plan code only using(CanLoad auth guards)
2. **Can this approach work?** As only that subscription specific code will be downloaded on user machine.
3. I am not much clear about component html re-usability. As same component will render different html based on plan. **How can these be reused?**
4. **What other approach to follow if above does not work?** For scalable solution as tomorrow we may other plans.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You should look for some good tutorials on Angular 4/5. All your doubts will be cleared once you go through the angular docs

Comment: This is too much and too much opinion based. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is opinionated and most or your questions can be understood in the docs: https://angular.io/docs, but to give you some points to look up:

1. Lazy loading modules is how you will achieve this
2. This can be as simple as applying `*ngIf` and as complicated as creating all subscription components as presentation components rendering the data from services from subscription specific modules... https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-component-design-how-to-avoid-custom-event-bubbling-and-extraneous-properties-in-the-local-component-tree/ is a good start
3. The two links are a good start
4. Completely opinion based

Comment: Thanks Kyler for pointer and i also agree for point 1 lazy loading without route would work.But i was more concerned which is best approach(scalable) to handle this scenario..could you please sugges any other once..so that only relevant code(html,css,js) gets downloaded to user machine

Comment: .. for pointer and i also agree for point 1 lazy loading without route would work.But i was more concerned which is best approach(scalable) to handle this scenario..could you please sugges any other once..so that only relevant code(html,css,js) gets downloaded to user machine

Comment: If you only want certain components brought in to certain clients then you needs seperate modules that are lazy loaded based on clients subscription.